# How to play youtube video using feeds in sencha Touch2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to play youtube video using youtube feeds like `http://www.youtube.com/rss/user/userName/videos.rss`

```
xtype: 'nestedlist',
    title: 'Blog',
    iconCls: 'star',
    displayField: 'title',

    store: {
        type: 'tree',

        fields: [
            'title', 'link', 'author', 'contentSnippet', 'content',
            {name: 'leaf', defaultValue: true}
        ],

        root: {
            leaf: false
        },

        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.youtube.com/rss/user/JustinBieberVEVO/videos.rss',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
            }
        }
    },

    detailCard: {
        xtype: 'video',
        scrollable: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    listeners: {
        itemtap: function(nestedList, list, index, element, post) {
            this.getDetailCard().setHtml(post.get('content'));
        }
    }
},
```

when user click feed list then application play direct video
Please help me on this.